# My package is not auto linking in React Native

Tags: objective-c, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I am practicing on creating a React Native bridge. So far I am able to pass a string from Objective-C to JavaScript using the following codes:

**TestModule.h**

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface TestModule : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

**TestModule.m**

```
#import "TestModule.h"

@implementation TestModule

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(foo:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  NSString *testString = @"test";
  callback(@[testString]);
}

@end
```

Then in React Native:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text, NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { foo } = NativeModules.TestModule;

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('HELLO WORLD!');

  useEffect(() => foo(setText), []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

This works just fine in a **monolithic app**, but I want to export the method as a 3rd party dependency and move it to a different folder then added a `test-bridge.podspec` file.

**test-bridge.podspec**

```
package = JSON.parse(File.read('package.json'))

Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name = package['name']
  spec.version = package['version']
  spec.summary = package['description']
  spec.license = package['license']
  spec.homepage = package['homepage']
  spec.author = { package['author']['name'] => package['author']['email'] }
  spec.source = { git: package['repository']['url'] }
  spec.source_files = '*.{h,m}'
end
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-bridge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Some Description",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/dcangulo/test-bridge",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/dcangulo/test-bridge.git"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "David Angulo",
    "email": "hello@davidangulo.xyz",
    "url": "https://www.davidangulo.xyz"
  },
  "main": "index.js"
}
```

Then to install it on my app (created using `npx react-native init`) I run the following:

```
yarn add https://github.com/dcangulo/test-bridge
npx pod-install
```

However, `pod-install` does not link the package in the app and I get `null is not an object` error implying that `NativeModules.TestModule` is `null`.

Repo: https://github.com/dcangulo/test-bridge

What does my code lacking to enable autolinking using cocoapods?